# php redirect to different URL when reload

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

I cannot find the right solution to my problem.
I have a page, in that page every action you take must redirect to a specific URL. I tried with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
  window.history.forward();     
  function noBack() { 
    window.history.forward();
  } 
</script>
```

but if click the back button it will return in the previous page.
If I use a

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/?id=$q&title=exampe">
```

this just refresh on a specific time.
What I want is that when a user try to leave the page he must be redirected to a pescific page e.g. : example.com/?id=$q&title=exampe
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to create that meta tag:

```
<script>
document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="'+ [theURL] +'" id=$q&title=examp'e">');
</script>
```

Comment: sorry but this script don't work if I reload the page

Comment: Where are you getting the URL that you want to redirect them to?

Comment: I have a page called example.com/key.php?id=q&title=exam and I put the script just before the end of the Head tag, then the script should redirect the page to a page called example.com/del.php?id=q&title=exam. the first script not allow to go back, and I need the second script that redirect to a specific page. What I want achieve is that the user is forced to go only to a specific page whatever action he take.

Comment: I really don't see the problem here.  Your key.php will push the user to the del.php page.  If they go back, the key.php will bounce them forward again anyway.  And you form action should take care of where it goes forward.  You could look into <body onunload="myFunction()">, if you need something specific for if the user simply tries to leave.  But that may not be 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I did a simple script with window.location=myLink and then I called the function with onunload in the body tag. But the real solution to my problem was to put all in a blank page and call it with include.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to send a raw HTTP header without requiring JavaScript.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```